# Combining ranges of cells for search by color

Tags: google-sheets, cells

My question is really simple though I did not find an answer anywhere.

I am using a custom script function that counts cells with a specified color in a selected range.

> countColoredCells(range;range)

The first range is the range of cells to look into, and the second one is the cell that has the color we are looking for.

Here is the script I'm using :

```
    /**
* @param {range} countRange Range to be evaluated
* @param {range} colorRef Cell with background color to be searched for in countRange
* @return {number}
* @customfunction
*/

function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\;/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\;(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();

  var count = 0;

  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

Now that works for let's say `countColoredCells(A1:A3;W1)`, but what I want to do is to look into multiple ranges of cells in different tabs, and not just one. But if I try to do `countColoredCells(A1:A3;C1:C3;W1)` (what Sheets does when holding CTRL while selecting), the function doesn't have the correct number of arguments anymore.
The problem I have is that I want to select multiple ranges of **cells**, not their **values** (which is why arrays don't solve my problem).

So the question is really simple : Should the script be adapted, or is there a practical way to combine ranges into a new range of cells (symbol, function...) ?

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT : For now, I use this script for one range at a time and then a sum of all the returned results. Not best, but it works. Still leaving the question opened for people who can't afford to sum everything and not have it automated.